# How does printf %f work on a 32-bit float

Tags: c, printf, variadic-functions

The `%f` printf format code is specified as operating on a value of type `double` [[source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf)]. However, a simple test program demonstrates that it can also be used with values of type `float`. How does this work?

The equivalent case with integer types (e.g. `int` and `long long int`) "works" because on little-endian machines, the low-order bytes of a 32-bit integer happen to overlap the low-order bytes of a 64-bit integer, so as long as the upper bits are 0, you'll get the "right" answer.

But this cannot possibly be the case for `float` and `double`, because the floating point formats are not interchangeable like this. You simply cannot print a floating point value as a double without doing the (rather complicated) conversion into the other format. An attempt to do so by type-punning will simply print garbage.

On top of that, `printf` is variadic. The compiler doesn't necessarily know at compile time what format specifiers will be used, only the types of the arguments. Therefore the only thing I can surmise is that *all* `float` values passed to a variadic function would be upgraded to `double`, unconditionally. But it boggles my mind that I could have been programming in C for so long and not know this.

How is C doing the implicit coercion here?

Source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
  float x[2] = {M_PI, 0.0};
  printf("value of x: %.16e\n", x[0]);
  printf("size of x: %lu\n", sizeof(x[0]));

  double *xp = (double *)&x[0];
  printf("value of *xp: %.16e\n", *xp);
  printf("size of *xp: %lu\n", sizeof(*xp));

  double y = M_PI;
  printf("value of y: %.16e\n", y);
  printf("size of y: %lu\n", sizeof(y));

  int i[2] = {1234, 0};
  printf("value of i: %lld\n", i[0]);
  printf("sizeof of i: %lu\n", sizeof(i[0]));

  long long *ip = (long long *)&i[0];
  printf("value of i: %lld\n", *ip);
  printf("sizeof of i: %lu\n", sizeof(*ip));

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
value of x: 3.1415927410125732e+00
size of x: 4
value of *xp: 5.3286462644388174e-315
size of *xp: 8
value of y: 3.1415926535897931e+00
size of y: 8
value of i: 1234
sizeof of i: 4
value of i: 1234
sizeof of i: 8
```

Compile command and version:

```
$ gcc test_float.c -o test_float
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 5.5.0-12ubuntu1~16.04) 5.5.0 20171010
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [Variadic arguments](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/variadic) and [Default argument promotions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Default_argument_promotions):

> At the function call, each argument that is a part of the variable argument list undergoes special implicit conversions known as [default argument promotions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Default_argument_promotions).

.

> Each argument of integer type undergoes integer promotion (see below), and **each argument of type float is implicitly converted to the type double**.

Answer (score 6):

> Therefore the only thing I can surmise is that all float values passed to a variadic function would be upgraded to double, unconditionally.

Yes - that's precisely right.

From the C standard;

> 6.5.2.2.7 The ellipsis notation in a function prototype declarator causes argument type conversion to stop after the last declared
>   parameter. The default argument promotions are performed on trailing
>   arguments.

And the "default argument promotions" rules will promote `float` to `double`, the relevant part being:

> 6.5.2.2.6 If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does not include a prototype, the integer promotions are
>   performed on each argument, and arguments that have type float are
>   promoted to double.